# What posted recipes have you personally brewed multiple times and have had success with?

Tags: recipe-formulation, competition

Brewing recipies posted online are very numerous, but I get the feeling that a lot of them might be 'ideas', and maybe have never been even brewed.

I'm sure some members here have had success with posted recipes or posted recipes they have had sucçess with.

If you have repeatedly brewed essentially the same recipe several times, like the result, maybe even won a ribbon, and that recipe is posted somewhere, I think it would be valuable to have a place to collect those links.

Comment: Not sure if this should be a wiki, and if so, how to convert it.

Comment: http://meta.homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11/recipe-questions

Answer (score 1):

I think an 'answer' to this dilemma would be Brewing Classic Styles by Jamil.  All award-winning, all relatively simple.  The problem of the internet's wealth of information is definitely a lack of quality of the information.

Comment: I have done exactly this and for the same reasons. These are proven recipes, and all but one has come out really well. Some people scoff at the unoriginality of it, but I want to make beer that I can drink every day.  This book helps me do that.

Comment: Hey, thats the Garrett Oliver method/Mr. Miyagi method (first learn stand, then learn fly).  Creating your own recipes is great, and can yield amazing results, but can also result in garbage.  I personally think too many homebrewers immediately go for the Double Chocolate Imperial Peanut Butter Porter before they can brew a solid Baltic again and again, and it results in an underattenuated unbalanced gloppy mess.